# FFmpeg/Command line - any way around the maximum character limit?

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

I have a large number of videos that I am processing with FFmpeg, and I am applying unique filter settings to each video in a single complex filter graph.

However, I have a current roadblock where I am unable to exceed 8191 characters do to a windows limitation in the command prompt.

Is there any way for me to get around this with the native windows cmd?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a Windows limitation, save the filter complex to a file and load it from there.

```
ffmpeg -i 1 -i 2 ... -filter_complex_script mysavedscript.txt -map a -map b output
```

Comment: I had to use `-filter_script` in FFmpeg 3.4

Comment: there are both -filter_complex_script and -filter_script